# How to fix double free or corrupted

Tags: c, linked-list

This is the part of my code which is for deleting nodes of a circular linked list. When running the program, it gives the right output, but states double free or corruption (fasttop). How should I fix this ?

```
   void deleter(struct Node ** head, int deletespace, int length){
    struct Node * current = *head;
    int delete_counter = 0;
    while(delete_counter < length-1){
        /*to count for skipping/not eliminating the first k-1 contestents */
        for (int i = 1; i < deletespace-1 ; i++){
            current = current->next;
        }
        /*assigns the position of the content to be eliminated to p*/
        struct Node * p = current->next;
        /*moves the counter to the k+1 contestent*/
        current->next = p->next;
        /*eliminated the contestent*/
        free(p);
        p == NULL;
        current = current->next;
        delete_counter++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", current->info) ;
    free(current);
    current == NULL;
    }
```

Comment: This line does nothing: `p == NULL;`  perhaps you meant `p = NULL;`?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons `p = NULL;` wouldn't do anything either though, since this is a local variable which isn't used after free().

Comment: How does `free(current);` make sense in combination with `free(p);`? It would seem that you want either of these but not both at once?

Comment: @Lundin Fair enough.  I didn't really dig any further after I saw that suspicious line.

Comment: It turns out, that it was a silly error. It is indeed "p = NULL" & "current = NULL" instead of using == @ChristianGibbons, you were right hahaha, thanks for the help !